# Understanding the statement of Q.15 in section 2.1 in AT.

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

The question is given below:

> [image]

**My questions are:**

1-I do not understand the part of the question starting from the word hence (the first part I have already proved it), could anyone explain this part for me please?

2- A stupid question, do we have to prove the part starting from the word hence?

Comment: 2. Yes. 1. Try to prove 2.

Comment: Could you help me in proving it, please? @Berci

Comment: We get a long exact sequence of homology groups: $\dots \to H_n(A) \to H_n(X) \to H_n(X,A) \to H_{n-1}(A)\to\dots$ and apply 1.

Comment: And why we get this long Exact sequence ?@Berci

Comment: See the reference given by W.Zhan. Also, you can check this out: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_homology

Comment: Anyway, I would presume, this exercise is given as homework only after introducing this long exact sequence for relative homology.

Comment: And what is the relation of the inclusion map to what we have proved in part 1? and what (A, X) (of part 2)corresponds to in part 1? @Berci

Comment: The condition $H_n(X,A) =0$ is the connection: it makes every third element $0$ in the long exact sequence, so the intermediate maps will be both injective and surjective by 1.

Comment: And why specifically the inclusion map is the map that induces this isomorphism? @Berci

Comment: Also the sequence in part 1 contains only five spaces but the long exact sequence contains countably infinite @Berci

Comment: The inclusion map induces the internal morphisms $H_n(A)\to H_n(X)$. The other maps are zero. The sequence from 1. is put on the infinite sequence infinite many times: the middle object of 1. goes to $H_n(X,A)$.

Comment: But the inclusion map is not surjective @Berci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line refers to a result in general for *Abelian categories*.

---

It is sufficient for you to work with the category for abelian groups. You may attempt the general case as an exercise. For starters, you need to know:

(a) What it means to be exact.

(b) What it means to be injective and surjective.

---

Now I will prove one part of the first line.

$A \rightarrow B$ is surjective iff $im (A \rightarrow B) = B$ iff $\ker (B \rightarrow C)= B$ iff im $(B \rightarrow C) =0$

$D \rightarrow E$ is inejctive iff $\ker (D \rightarrow E)=0$ iff $im(C \rightarrow D) =0$ iff $\ker(C \rightarrow D)=C$.

Now result follows if you know what (a) means.

---

For the second part,

Apply the first to the LES in homology groupos induced from the SES,

$$ C_*(A) \rightarrow C_*(X) \rightarrow C_*(X)/C_*(A) $$
In which case, we have 
$$\cdots \rightarrow H_n(A) \rightarrow H_n(X) \rightarrow H_n(X,A) \rightarrow H_{n-1}(A) \rightarrow \cdots $$ 
If $H_n(X,A)=0$ , then by first part $H_n(A) \rightarrow H_n(X)$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Is this a proof for the part starting by the word "Hence"?

Comment: Oh I have misread, so you want a proof for the second part?

Comment: The first part I already know how to prove it. I need a help in the part starting by the word "Hence"

Comment: You use the LES induced from SES, 
$$ C_*(A) \rightarrow C_*(X) \rightarrow C_*(X)/C_*(A) $$

Comment: Yes, please if you donot mind

Comment: why and how ? I do not know how to do this

Comment: For a reference of how to derive LES from SES, see Weibel's, Introduction to Homological Algebra.

Comment: But the second part contains "iff" not "if" only

Comment: And what is the relation of the inclusion map to what we have proved in part 1? and what (A, X) (of part 2)corresponds to in part 1?

Comment: And why specifically the inclusion map is the map that induces this isomorphism?

Comment: I do not understand from where the isomorphism in your last line came, I can not see any isomorphism in part 1. Could you clarify this point, please?